# How to type pipe with the ABNT2 layout?

Tags: keyboard

I'm used to the [ABNT2 brazilian portuguese layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout), which is very nice for both programming and typing with accents, but my [apple keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD0dB.jpg) lacks keys that are standard for such layout, like one on the left of Z and a fourth on the right of M. As a result, slashes and question mark need extra work to type, namely pressing alt-q, alt-shift-q and alt-w. But nothing for pipe.

So I wondered how I could type a pipe without messing with [ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-os-x)?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a shortcut for it in system prefs/keyboard/text/replace with

Minimum 2 characters I think.